# Firebase Performance Monitoring and Retrofit

Tags: android, firebase, retrofit2, firebase-performance

I have integrated Firebase Performance Monitoring in one of my projects. In that project, I use Retrofit to manage my network requests.

Sadly, none of the requests made through Retrofit are visible in the "Network Requests" tab of Firebase Performance.

Here are the only things I see :

[image: Firebase Performance Monitoring]

Can somebody tell me what I need to do in order to see my Retrofit-managed network requests in Firebase Performance?

Thank you

Comment: What version of retrofit and okhttp are you using?

Comment: I currently use Retrofit 1.9.0 with OkHttp 2.4.0 I'll update both of them and see if the problem is solved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just started reading up on this - sounds interesting. Check that;

1. You are using a supported `OkHttp` RE:

> Performance Monitoring only supports monitoring HTTP/S network
>   requests made using the OkHttp HTTP client version 3.x.x.

Retrofit 1, the original can use OkHttp 1 or 2 if I remember correctly. However, Retrofit 2 [enforces 3.x.x+](https://github.com/square/retrofit/releases). Check which is pulled in by running `./gradlew <insert-module-name>:dependencies`

2. You've waited for 12hrs (Looking at the date-times I think you're good there!)
3. If (1) and (2) don't help - then debug using the approach described in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android?authuser=0) and adding this to the relevant `AndroidManifest.xml`;

   < meta-data android:name="firebase_performance_logcat_enabled" android:value="true" / >

...dumps what's going on to logcat by the sounds of it. Report back! My bets are on (1).

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I currently use Retrofit 1.9.0 with OkHttp 2.4.0
I'll update both of them and see if the problem is solved.

Comment: Big update that one... Retrofit 1.9 --> latest! Good luck!

Comment: Actually, it was such a big work to upgrade Retrofit and OkHttp in the project that we decided to do it later. So I can't say :/

Comment: I have upgraded Retrofit in my project and now I see everything in Firebase Performance. Thanks :)